# No ways for whites

Tags: analysis

I'm analyzing a situation that happened to me in a game ... is when I move my black queen to this position. Finally I won, but ... is there any chance to stop the attack for White?

```
6k1/2p2pp1/2b4p/1p2b2r/8/1BNQ3P/1PP2qP1/4R2K w - - 2 28
```

There is the png till this position

```
1. e4 e5
2. Bc4 Nc6
3. Nf3 Nf6
4. Nc3 d6
5. h3 Be7
6. d4 exd4
7. Nxd4 Bd7
8. O-O O-O
9. Bg5 h6
10. Bxf6 Bxf6
11. Nxc6 Bxc6
12. Re1 Re8
13. Qf3 Qd7
14. Ra1d1 Re7
15. Rd2 Ra8e8
16. Rd2e2 a6
17. a4 b5
18. axb5 axb5
19. Bb3 Qc8
20. Qd3 Qb7
21. f3 Qb6+
22. Kh2 Re5
23. f4 Rh5
24. e5 dxe5
25. fxe5 Re8xe5
26. Rxe5 Bxe5+
27. Kh1 Qf2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

White looks doomed, but `Rg1` seems to be the best line of defense though Black is merely gifted with the under-1800 brilliancy prize.

```
[FEN "6k1/2p2pp1/2b4p/1p2b2r/8/1BNQ3P/1PP2qP1/4R2K w - - 2 28"]

1. Rg1 Bxg2+ 2. Rxg2 Rxh3+ 3. Qxh3 Qf1+ 4. Rg1 Qxh3#
```

Other moves lose immediately.

Answer (score 0):

25. Qg6 is killing blow (attack on both f7 and Rh5). I think it was white's last chance.
    Also 26.Qg6 can stop black's attack but black still has upper hand. For example:
    26.Qg6 Be8 27.Ne4 Rhf5 28. Nxf6+ Rxf6 29.Qd3 and black is better.

Comment: What about 25. Qg6 Qxe1#

Comment: How can queen on b6 takes e1?!

Comment: I see the black Q on `f2`

Comment: On move 25, black queen stands on b6. It's after move 27 when queen comes to f2.

Comment: I see. You were going back a few moves.  Nevermind.  I didn't downvote that, I just didn't understand what you were saying.

Comment: In final position I think there is no way to save white.

Comment: n1. White could won game with this move